# Access control in stack panel of listbox

Tags: windows-phone-7, xaml

I have this xaml

```
<ListBox x:Name="listBox"
         ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
         Tap="listBox_Tap">
  <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
      <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" />
    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
  </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
  <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
      <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
        <Image Name="cPix"
               Source="{Binding Image}"
               Stretch="None"
               Margin="0,0,5,5"
               ToolTipService.Placement="Bottom"
               ToolTipService.ToolTip="{Binding Name}" />
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"
                   HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                   Foreground="Black" />
      </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
  </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

the concept is that, i want the listbox to lazy load images, there will be a placeholder image first, and while the images finish downloading, the placeholder give way to the downloaded image.

Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can solve this in your `ViewModel`. Here is an example pseudo code:

```
public BitmapImage Image
{
    get
    {
        if (_image == null)
            ImageManager.LoadImageAsync(_imageUri).ContinueWith(t=> Image = t.Result);
        return _image;
    }
    set
    {
        _image = value;
        NotifyPropertyChanged("Image");
    }
}
```

Your `ImageManager` would load images asynchronously, whether from cache, `IsolatedStorage` or web and when done, it would complete the internal `Task`.

Comment: Thanks for the pseudo code, did not really understand the part:  NotifyPropertyChanged("Image"); could you please elaborate further

Comment: That is just a common implementation for `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface. It just calls `PropertyChanged`.